# Difference between adding instance methods with Active Concern and a regular ruby module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport-concern

What is the difference between adding instance methods whith active concern and through the normal ruby def keyword on the module?

```
module MonsterConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def engage_rage
    end

    def chew_bones
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
module MonsterConcern
  def engage_rage
  end

  def chew_bones
  end
end
```

Comment: In your case, the `included` is not needed in the concern. [Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)'s an example of the difference between a regular module and one that extends the concern. In the `included` section, you usually include `scope`, `belongs_to`, callbacks such as `before_validation` ...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no difference if the only thing you are interested in is instance methods.

The `ActiveSupport::Concern` advantage is the ability to define class methods, and to handle some nasty module interdependencies better (related to calling class methods in the `included` block).

You can read more here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html